# fullcalendar modal bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

My website uses Bootstrap 3  I am trying to make the modal for click to event in fullcalendar the's open but the event title and content is not changing please help me thanks

```
eventClick: function(event, calEvent, jsEvent, view, element) {
    $('#view_event').modal({
      title: event.title,
      content: event.content
    });
}

<div class="modal fade" id="view_event">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="event_title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        view
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" data-option="remove">remove</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-option="edit">edit</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `title` and `content` options in twitter bootstrap modal component.

You can change the title and content of a Modal, directly using jQuery selectors:

```
eventClick: function(event, calEvent, jsEvent, view, element) {
    $('#view_event .modal-title').text(event.title);
    $('#view_event .modal-body').text(event.content);
}
```